# WCF Service with Active Directory Authentication

Tags: asp.net, wcf, authentication, active-directory

I am writing a WCF Service which would allow access to operations based on AD user group. If the logged in user is part of `groupA`, allow him to do `operationA`, but not `operationB` and so on and so forth. Now for this I have to pass `NetworkCredentials` to the service like

```
factory.Credentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = 
                     TokenImpersonationLevel.Identification;
factory.Credentials.Windows.AllowNtlm = true;
factory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential.username = "username";
factory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential.password = "pwd";
factory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential.domain = "mycompany.com";
```

I want that the user need not enter his credentials for calling service operation. It should take from `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`. Can anyone help me out in this regards as to how to pass network credentials.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just specify the security mode to be "Windows integrated" security on your binding? This is the default on net.Tcp and wsHttp bindings - the Windows credentials of the currently logged in user will be sent across the wire to the server.

No need to explicitly set those credentials again, really.

Comment: Do you mean I should just remove the above code from my client? If yes, it still takes the ASPNET account as the default credentials. Can u post in some code to help me out? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: AHA - ASP.NET - you didn't mention that in your original POST!

Comment: It depends on how you have ASP.NET set up - if you connect to your ASP.NET site anonymously, you'll "loose" your credentials and ASP.NET will connect to your WCF service with its own credentials. If you have set up Windows authentication for the ASP.NET app (in IIS Manager), you should be fine, I think.